# Urls won't open with added url scheme

Tags: swift, google-chrome, url, plist

I want to open urls with google chrome. This works just fine if I replace the url prefix with 'googlechrome://' (ergo google chrome opens the url).

I do however also want to check if chrome is installed for which I am using the 'canOpenUrl' method for which again I understand I need to make sure I have the respective url schemes added. So far so good, I added 'googlechrome' and 'googlechromes' to my url schemes in my plist and the 'canOpenUrl' method returns as true. However nothing happens, google chrome simply won't open. Anything obvious that I am missing?

This code works just fine, google Chrome opens so long I don't have any of the url schemes in my plist:

```
if let googleUrl = URL(string: "googlechrome" + "\(urlString.replaceStringPrefix())") {
    print("openUrl, googleUrl: ", googleUrl)
    UIApplication.shared.open(googleUrl, options: [:])
}
```

This below returns true for canOpenUrl with the respective plist entry, but nothing happens, Google chrome won't open:

```
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>googlechrome</string>
        <string>googlechromes</string>
        <string>googlechrome-x-callback</string>
    </array>



if let googleUrl = URL(string: "googlechrome" + "\(urlString.replaceStringPrefix())") {
     print("openUrl, googleUrl: ", googleUrl)
     if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(googleUrl) {
           print("Can open url with Chrome, url: ", googleUrl)
           UIApplication.shared.open(googleUrl, options: [:])
     } else {
           print("Cannot open url with Chrome, falling back to Safari")
           if let safariUrl = URL(string: urlString) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(safariUrl, options: [:])
           }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit. canOpenUrl will return true with the plist entry above, the correct key to actually open in the respective apps is LSApplicationQueriesSchemes, which results in this:

```
        <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>googlechrome</string>
            <string>googlechromes</string>
            <string>googlechrome-x-callback</string>
        </array>
```